# Need material for character anatomy in a 2D game. Spartan Like, See Picture

Tags: 2d, platformer

I'm creating my art for an 2d based IOS game. I know some basic anatomy as you can see by the picture but I have no idea how I will make draw the pics for animation of the character walking, attacking with his sword and protecting himself with shield.

Is there any anatomy reference for 2d game out there, book or anything else?

for your information, I did try to find but all of stuff I found are very amateur and incomplete

The picture was my attempt of creating a example of the character walking, which I'm not happy with

[image]

please help, thanks

Update:

Since I am in a hurry I decided I would copy the anatomy from other 2d games, it is not that clean but at least I wanna be able to start it. The question is still open.

[image]

Comment: There have been martial arts books with diagrams for centuries, if you just need inspiration I'd suggest googling for medieval martial arts.  It's worth noting that perfect historical accuracy won't serve you particularly well, since greek war was mainly fought in a phalanx formation.  A quick search turns up this: http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/manufacturing/text/viking_sword_technique.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would have done the same. You could as well try some kind of "poor guy's Motion capturing" by recording yourself doing the specific moves or by using some 3d modelling software to do it. The latter might be easier in case you want a deformed character.

Create key frames using still Images (3-4 should be enough; maybe even only 2 depending on what you want) and then layering to draw your character on top.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at classical art and animation references. The basics are the same, there's nothing special about games or "2d games" that set them apart in terms of the art.

A great reference for animation is Preston Blair's book on cartoon animation:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/7582342/Preston-Blair-Cartoon-Animation

You can also search youtube for videos of motion capture or just people performing the actions you want to animate, and use those as reference.